# Where does 'attahiyaatu lillahi was salawaatu' come from?

Tags: source-identification, arabic, tashahhud

Can someone point me to where this comes from? I don't know Arabic so I've had to transliterate:

> *attahiyaatu lillahi was salawaat at tayyibaat. as salaamu alan nabee wa rahmatullahi wa barakat. as salaamu alaynaa wa alal ibaad as saaliheen. ashhadu alaa ilaaha il allah washhadu anna mohammed ur rasoolallah*

Comment: AFAIK this is NOT from Quran but it is part of prayer rituals as has been narrated through the Sunna and Ahadith.

Comment: I knew it was from the prayer ritual, but I had assumed that it was taken from the quran.

Comment: I currently have no direct source but IIRC I read that it is part of the conversation between Prophet (SAAW+PBUH) and Allah during Israa and Miraj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Attahiyyaatu lillaahi wassalawaatu , wattayyibaatu , assalaamu 'alayka 'ayyuhan-Nabiyyu wa rahmatullaahi wa barakaatuhu, assalaamu 'alaynaa wa 'alaa 'ibaadillaahis-saaliheen. 'Ash-hadu 'an laa 'ilaaha 'illallaahu wa 'ash-hadu 'anna Muhammadan 'abduhu wa Rasooluhu.
>
> All greetings of humility are for Allah , and all prayers and goodness . Peace be upon you , O Prophet , and the mercy of Allah and His blessings . Peace be upon us and upon the righteous slaves of Allah . I bear witness that there is none worthy of worship but Allah , and I bear witness that Muhammad is His slave and His Messenger.
>
> Reference: Al-Bukhari, Muslim 1/301. See also Al-Asqalani, Fathul-Bal 1/13

From [Fortress of Muslim](http://www.islamawareness.net/Dua/Fortress/022.html)